# Copying from network share using BAT

Tags: windows, batch-file

What's the best way to copy a file from a network share to the local file system using a Windows batch file?  Normally, I would use "net use *" but using this approach how can I get the drive letter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you just use the full UNC path to the file?

```
copy \\myserver\myshare\myfolder\myfile.txt c:\myfiles
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the drive letter for `net use`.  Put this in the command prompt for more info:

```
net use /?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xcopy` and `robocopy`:

```
xcopy "\\server\share\path" "destination"
```

```
robocopy "\\server\share\path" "destination"
```